# How to get a String from an AsyncSnapshot<String> in Flutter FutureBuilder?

Tags: async-await, dart, future, flutter

I have an image I would like to load from a `NetworkImage(url)`.  I'm populating a `Future<String> images;` variable from an initial function and now I'm having trouble getting my FutureBuilder to read it as a String.  I'm getting the error on the url as "The argument type AsyncSnapshot can not be assigned to the parameter type String" Here is my code...

```
Future<String> images;

Future<Null> getData() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var userid = user.uid;
    await fb.child('users/${userid}').onValue.listen((Event event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        name = event.snapshot.value['displayName'];
        images = event.snapshot.value['image'];
      } else {
        name = "MyFavKPop";
      }
    });
  }

new FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: images, // a Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return new Text('Press button to start');
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Awaiting result...');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        else
          return new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(snapshot.data.toString()) // getting NetworkImageError ..looking for String not Future<String>,
            radius:  75.0,
          );
     }
 }),
```

Answer (score 2):

The resulting data is the [`AsyncSnapshot.data`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html), not the instance of the snapshot itself.  In your example, the cases should be:

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
  case ConnectionState.none:
    return new Text('Press button to start');
  case ConnectionState.waiting:
    return new Text('Awaiting result...');
  default:
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    else {
      return new CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(snapshot.data),
        radius:  75.0,
      );
    }
}
```

EDIT: The second issue is that you are not creating `images` correctly - you are assigning a String to a Future.  Instead try using a completer to create a Future when your `getData` method finishes running.

```
Completer<String> _imageCompleter = new Completer<String>();
Future<String> get images => _imageCompleter.future;

Future<Null> getData() async {
  ...
  _imageCompleter.complete(event.snapshot.value['image']);
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>' of 'future' `  even when I use `snapshot.data.toString()`.  Have any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include where you are getting this error?

Comment: Added Error @ CircleAvatar